# GoogleCloudMessaging bundle and comparing strings

Tags: android, string, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM to receive and display notifications, this is working correctly. I am now trying to get different methods to be called depending on what is in the received message.

The GcmIntertService is basically a copy of the demo provided. I have added the following
to set a String with the value of the received gcm message.

```
    String string1 = extras.getString("message");
```

Next I am setting my conditions, firstly check if the new String text equals a pre-defined string, my keyword.

```
   if(string1.equals(string2))
                {

                    method1();

            }
            else{
                 sendNotification(extras.getString("message"));
                 Log.i(TAG, "Message: " + extras.toString());
            }
```

Now this worked as expect but only once, if I send a test message again containing the keyword, nothing happens.
But if its not the key word, it correctly uses the second sendNotification method.
Am I declaring or comparing the strings incorrectly ?

for testing method1 is very simple, just logging.

Its really wrecking my head, would love some help. Cheers.

Comment: If, as you say, you get the notification only when not sending the keyword, it means that the condition works and method1() is called whenever you send the keyword. Perhaps you should post the code of method1. Another possibility is that on the second time you sent the keyword, it didn't arrive to the device. You should add logging before the condition to verify that the message is received.

Comment: Yes, I tried that , at the moment method1 just contains Log.i(TAG,"method1 called"); but this never appears in the log, literally nothing happens in logcat, but put anything other than the keyword and the second method for displaying the notification displays. Its like as you say, the message isnt arriving but I can send multiple other messages and they all arrive, only the keyword on dosnt, or at least arrives but does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant explain this but this is working now after rebuilding the vm and cleaning the project. 
thanks anyway.